# enum not getting called in constructor

Tags: java

I'm trying to build some Dota2-like classes, with simple details. I got stuck at one point where I need my hero's attribute in Main, but the constructor for it doesn't work. Here is the code for Hero class:

```
 enum attribute {
    Strength, Intelligence, Agility
 };

public class Hero extends Unit {
private int level;
private static int str;
private static int intl;
private static int agi;
private static attribute heroAttribute;

public attribute getAttribute() {
    return heroAttribute;
}

private static int attributeDamage() {
    if (heroAttribute == attribute.Strength)
        return str;
    else if (heroAttribute == attribute.Intelligence)
        return intl;
    else
        return agi;
}

public Hero(int level, int str, int intl, int agi, attribute heroAttribute) {
    super(200 + 20 * str, attributeDamage());
    System.out.println("A hero has been spawned.");
}

}
```

and the Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hero h1= new Hero(25,400,30,30,attribute.Agility);
        System.out.println(h1.getAttribute());


    }
}
```

What I get is that I have null "attribute" value.

Comment: Where do you believe you're assigning to the `heroAttribute` field? I don't see that anywhere. (It's also very weird that it's a static field...)

Answer (score 0):

Try put this attributes without the static, and initiate these attributes...

```
private int str;
private int intl;
private int agi;
private attribute heroAttribute;

public Hero(int level, int str, int intl, int agi, attribute heroAttribute) {
   this.str = str;
   this.intl = intl;
   this.ai = agi;
   this.heroAttribute = heroAttribute;
   super(200 + 20 * str, attributeDamage());
System.out.println("A hero has been spawned.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to create new enum class that containt those 3 attribute and then, implement them.
by the way, all enum entities should be upper case like: STRENGTH, AGILITY, INTELLIGENT

```
public enum HeroAttribute {
        STRENGTH("str"),
        AGILITY("agi"),
        INTELLIGENT("intl");

        private String literal;

        HeroAttribute(String literal) {
            this.literal = literal;
        }

        public String getLiteral() {
            return literal;
        }
    }
```